# Iterating through a Dataframe and Checking the Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe of orders delivery:

```
   Customer     Date    
1   Jay         2018-04-16
2   Anthony     2018-04-10
3   Anne        2018-05-01
```

I want to make another column which says which orders are late

```
   Customer     Date         Status
1   Jay         2018-04-16    OK
2   Anthony     2018-04-10    Late
3   Anne        2018-05-01    Ok
```

I´ve already turned the field Date into a Datetime format (datetime64[ns])

Here is my code:

```
def Status(x):
    if x < dt.datetime.today()
        return 'late'
    else:
        return 'ok'
df['Status'] = df['Date'].apply(Status)
```

I am getting the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-100-c389a139a796>", line 2
    if x < dt.datetime.today()
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should I do?

Comment: `if x < dt.datetime.today():`

Comment: use `np.where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Status'] = np.where( df['Date']< dt.datetime.today(), 'late','ok')
print (df)
  Customer       Date Status
1      Jay 2018-04-16     ok
2  Anthony 2018-04-10   late
3     Anne 2018-05-01     ok
```

Problem is you missing last `:`:

```
if x < dt.datetime.today():
```